# Android emulator status bar disappears after a while

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

Android emulator status bar disappears after a while . Also button for see the background running apps does not work after a while ! ( Using Flutter version `2.0.1` , `Google pixel 4 (API 30) emulator` , `Android 11` )

*Note :* When I create a new emulator there is NOT any problem with emulator **but after a while it doesn't work** even with restart and ...

**Status bar issue :**

[image]

**See running apps on the background issue :**

[image]

Comment: It looks like system UI has crashed and stopped working. Do you get any error dialogs when this occurs? Also it's weird it doesn't work after restart even for a little, just be sure you're doing a cold boot and not restoring a snapshot.

Comment: @Pawel I do not get any error dialog and when I do a cold boot for that emulator it works fine but as I mentioned , I guess it will crash again because even with creating a new emulator it'll be broken after a short

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem with emulators (no matter of device or API level), my status bar/notification bar/menu bar were missing after Android Studio update. What helped in my case, was go to **AVD manager -> wipe data -> restart.**[image]